# How to clear VTK points

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, point-cloud-library, pcl

I am new to vtk and I am writing an app to draw multiple shapes. The shapes are drawn using point picking event as follow:

```
void Visualizer::pointPickingEventOccurred (const pcl::visualization::PointPickingEvent &event)
 {
    std::cout << "[INOF] Point picking event occurred." << std::endl;

      float x, y, z;
      if (event.getPointIndex () == -1)
      {
         return;
      }
      event.getPoint(x, y, z);
      std::cout << "[INOF] Point coordinate ( " << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << std::endl;
      
      points->InsertNextPoint(x, y, z);


 }
```

points here is a vtk point list:

```
vtkNew<vtkPoints> points;
```

I am trying to clear `points` so I can resize it and get new points for each shape but I have not found a way to clear the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple call to **points->Reset()** will do the trick.
It will make the object look empty without actually releasing the memory.

Comment: I have tried it but I get an error saying it does not exist!

Comment: Is it an undefined reference? Did you include vtkPoints.h? Can you paste the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Does `Initialize()` do the trick?